# nth-child selector to prevent nested items selection

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>        
</ul>
```

When I use the following selector:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass("someclass");
```

it selects both Item 1 as well as Item 2.1. However I want that only Item 1 be selected. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [*child combinator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) rather than a [*descendant combinator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) by adding an `>`, and qualify the `ul` by using the `id` instead of the tag:

```
$("#menu > li:nth-child(1)").addClass("someclass"); 
// ^---  ^--- here
```

That way, it's only looking for direct children, and only of `#menu` (not all other `ul`s).

Live example:

```js
$("#menu > li:nth-child(1)").addClass("someclass");
```

```css
.someclass {
  background-color: #eb0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>        
</ul>
```

Comment: spot on. Thanks @T.J Crowder!

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is

```
$("#menu > li:nth-child(1)").addClass("someclass");
```

But it's possible to use this : (only if #menu ul is the first ul of the page)

```
$("ul li:first").addClass("someclass");
```